# Django transaction and racing condition

Tags: django, transactions, race-condition

I have the following Django code:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    items = Item.objects.all()
    for item in items:
        item.count += 1
    Item.objects.bulk_update(items, ['count'])
```

Does this code still contains the racing condition, despite the transaction?
My understanding is that transaction doesn't lock the rows for read, so several threads running the same code might read the same count value so as a result it might not be incremented proper number of times?

Comment: Why not `Item.objects.update(count=F('count')+1)`, this is a single atomic query.

Comment: Thanks, I completely agree with you solution. But the question is about the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. I have created the following test code, and ran it with psql (PostgreSQL) 10.12

```
def task():
    with transaction.atomic():
        item = Item.objects.get(pk=1)
        item.value += 1
        item.save()


def test(request):
    item = Item.objects.update_or_create(pk=1, defaults={'value': 0})

    threads = [Thread(target=task) for foo in range(0, 10)]
    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    return HttpResponse('finished')
```

After running this code I can confirm that it contains a racing condition, and the result value in the Item table is generally less then 10.

Also this racing condition can be fixed by either using select_for_update or an F function.

Comment: I ran your code using Django 4.2.9, postgres:13 and Python 3.11 with fixed typo and I always get value of 10 in the end. The only change I have done is fixing typo in select_for_update.get(pk=1) it should be select_for_update().get(pk=1)

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry. I edited my answer now. I have added select_for_update as one of the experiments, and accidentally posted a version with it here. Of course, select_for_update fixes the racing condition, so the test should be run without it.

Comment: Maybe edit your answer to include select_for_update with explanation that it fixes race condition issue? That would make complete answer

Comment: Done, added a short message.